# LOG/print mongo options of mongoclient created using spring

Tags: spring, mongodb

For a spring based project I am  using mongoTemplate to query mongo DB.
For this I have used systemProperties to configure mongo options  .

Now I want to print the value of these mongo options in my server's LOG, but unable to find a suitable way to do this. Kindly suggest. Following is my spring mongo xml.

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context" xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
xmlns:aop="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop" xmlns:task="http://www.springframework.org/schema/task" xmlns:mongo="http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/mongo"
xsi:schemaLocation="
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.1.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/mongo http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/mongo/spring-mongo-1.0.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.1.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-3.1.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop-2.0.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/task http://www.springframework.org/schema/task/spring-task-3.1.xsd">



<!-- Mongo Template for Test -->
<mongo:mongo replica-set="#{systemProperties['mongoTest.replicaset']}" id="mongoCocofs">
    <mongo:options auto-connect-retry="true" connections-per-host="#{systemProperties['mongoTest.connPerHost']?:'80'}" threads-allowed-to-block-for-connection-multiplier="#{systemProperties['mongoTest.threadAllowedForConnMultiplier']?:'5'}" slave-ok="true"/>
</mongo:mongo>

<mongo:db-factory dbname="test" mongo-ref="mongoTest" id="mongoDbFactoryTest" />

<bean id="mongoTemplateTest" class="org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoTemplate">
    <constructor-arg name="mongoDbFactory" ref="mongoDbFactoryCocofs" />
</bean>

<context:annotation-config />
```

Answer (score 0):

Solved it.
We can print it by calling following functions on a mongoTemplate bean:

```
mongoTemplate.getDb().getMongo().getMongoOptions()
```